# unity animator component breaks in nested if statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nested

Trying use component methods in nested if else statements however at 2nd depth compiler doesn't recognize the component
I'm assuming nested statements are the issue since;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator=GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("w")){
            animator.SetBool("isWalk",true);
        }
        else
            animator.SetBool("isWalk",true);
    }
}
```

This code works fine with no problems

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator=GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("1")){
            if(animator.getBool("hasWeapon")){
                animator.setBool("hasWeapon",false);
            }else{
                animator.setBool("hasWeapon",true);
            }
        }

        else if(Input.GetKey("w")){
            animator.SetBool("isWalk",true);
            if(Input.GetKey("shift")){
                animator.setBool("isRun",true);
                animator.setBool("isWalk",false);
            }else{
                animator.setBool("isRun",false);
            }
        }
        else
            animator.SetBool("isWalk",false);
    }
}
```

This code however throws "Animator does not contain a definition for 'getBool/setBool' and no accessible extension method 'getBool/setBool' accepting a first argument of type 'Animator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" only on lines 18,19,21,26, lines 25 and 34 throw no error
I realize i can simply use multiple if statements like true&&true, false&&true, false&&false etc. however i want to understand this problem

Comment: Casing counts friend. getBool is not GetBool.  setBool is not SetBool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use SetBool with capital 'S' and GetBool with capital 'G' like you used it in line

```
animator.SetBool("isWalk",true);
```

Comment: This is embarrassing but thanks